# Isomorphism of principal $G$-bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\pi: P\rightarrow M$ is a principal $G$-bundle we say $f:P\rightarrow P$ is automorphism of $P$ if $f$ is smooth, $f$ takes $\pi^{-1}(x)$ to $\pi^{-1}(x)$ and $f$ is compatible with $G$-action. Now this implies $f$ is bijective and I am trying to show $f^{-1}$ is isomorphism. But I have got stuck how to show $f^{-1}$ is smooth. (May be it is trivial but I can't see it). Any help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As smoothness is a local property, you may assume that $\pi$ is of the form $M\times G\to M$, in which case you can explicitly characterize its automorphisms,  write down their inverses and see that they are smooth as well. Does this help?

Comment: What are explicite characterizations?

Comment: @alphad: If you have a smooth map $M\times G\to M\times G$ which commutes both with the projection to $M$ and the right $G$-action by multiplication, how does it look like? It might help to look at the case where $M$ is a point first.

Comment: Oh, yes, I got it, thank you! $f(x,g)=(x,\phi(x)g)$ where $\phi$ is smooth.

Comment: @alphad: Exactly :)